# Convert scalar + std::array + std::tuple into a big tuple

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples

Consider the following code:

```
template <class Scalar, class Array, class Tuple>
class Test {};
```

where `Array` is a `std::array`, and `Tuple` is a `std::tuple`. In this class, I will have a lot of SFINAE, and I would like to create a big tuple called `Types` that will contain the complete list of types. This will allow me to test some conditions with variadic lists.

So the challenge is to create a type that will have the following behaviour. If:

- `Scalar = int`
- `Array = std::array<double, 3>`
- `Tuple = std::tuple<char, float, std::string>`

Then:

- `Types = std::tuple<int, double, double, double, char, float, std::string>`

which is the concatenation of the internal data of the `Scalar`, `Array` and `Tuple`.

How to do that ?

Comment: you want to concatenate arrays with tuples

Comment: [`std::tuple_cat`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8dbb18afcd1077d40ba97730bb58feca-0ef62b711c3b4aca94c9bcb419c937b3)~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct concat_tuples;

template<typename... T1, typename... T2>
struct concat_tuples<std::tuple<T1...>, std::tuple<T2...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<T1..., T2...>;
}; 

// n_tuple<int, 3>::type == std::tuple<int, int, int>
template<typename T, size_t n>
struct n_tuple;

template<typename T>
struct n_tuple<T, 0> 
{
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template<typename T, size_t n>
struct n_tuple
{
    using type = typename concat_tuples<
                    typename n_tuple<T, n-1>::type, 
                    std::tuple<T>
                >::type;
};

template <class Scalar, class Array, class Tuple>
struct Test;

template <class Scalar,  typename T, size_t n, typename... Ts>
struct Test<Scalar, std::array<T, n>, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = typename concat_tuples<
                    typename concat_tuples<
                        std::tuple<Scalar>, 
                        typename n_tuple<T, n>::type
                    >::type, 
                    std::tuple<Ts...>
                >::type;
};
```

Live demo [here](http://ideone.com/bqK7kp).

Answer (score 1):

Use a partial specialization to deduce the types, and Xeo's `tuple_cat` comment to put them together ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f3a92d226e99f954b50218d9abcdb63c-c944ac6b0eed3bfc48b1f78a894f6965):

```
template <typename ArrayType, std::size_t ArraySize, typename... Fields>
struct ArrayTuple : ArrayTuple<ArrayType, ArraySize-1, ArrayType, Fields...> {};
template <typename ArrayType, typename... Fields>
struct ArrayTuple<ArrayType, 0, Fields...> {
    using type = std::tuple<Fields...>;
};

template <typename, typename, typename> class Test;

template <typename Scalar, typename ArrayType, std::size_t ArraySize, typename... Fields>
class Test<Scalar, std::array<ArrayType, ArraySize>, std::tuple<Fields...>> {
public:
    // Modified tuple_cat code from Xeo's comment:
    using Tuple = std::tuple<Fields...>;
    using Types = decltype(
      std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<Scalar>(),
                     typename ArrayTuple<ArrayType, ArraySize>::type(),
                     std::declval<Tuple>()));
};
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't see the need for a partial specialization here. I just had the `using`s mirror his template parameters.

Comment: @Xeo It's poor man's SFINAE to eliminate non-arrays and non-tuples from the corresponding parameters.

Comment: I didn't know `tuple_cat` expands `std::array` like that. Nice.

Comment: @Xeo Experimenting with both methods, the error messages are fairly hideous. So yeah, the partial specialization isn't really buying anything.

Comment: By the Standard, all arguments to `std::tuple_cat` (after removing references) must be specializations of `std::tuple`.  It might work anyway if your implementation uses just the `std::tuple_size` and `std::tuple_element` interface, but don't count on it.

Comment: @aschepler: "Note: An implementation may support additional types in the parameter pack `Tuples` that support the `tuple`-like protocol, such as `pair` and `array`.". A shame they didn't require it.

Comment: @aschepler There you go, added array-to-tuple converter for portability.